# Access to undeclared static property - Strange Issue

Tags: php, laravel

I got some strange situation, i working with laravel in php, 
in my controllers i set "CompaniesController" and 2 more companies type controllers (Landlords & Clients).

got this error in the "ClientsController":

```
Access to undeclared static property: App\Http\Controllers\CRM\Pages\Companies\CompaniesController::$updates_roles
```

The clients & landlords controller reading the $updates_roles from CompaniesController, here is the code in the CompaniesController:

```
class CompaniesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Columns filters hide
     */

    public static $columns_filters_hide = [
        ....
    ];

    /**
     * Allow Sorting Columns
     */

    public static $columns_sorting = [
        ....
    ];

    /**
     * Query results values convert
     *
     * @var array
     */

    public static $query_results_value = [
        ....
    ];

    /**
     * Updates Roles
     *
     * @var array
     */

    public static $updates_roles = [
        'Companies' =>
        [
            'primary' => 'id',
            'fields'  =>
            [
                'name' => [
                    'required' => true
                ],
                'heb_name' => [
                    'required' => true
                ],
                'website'  => [],
                'linkdin'  => [],
                'facebook' => [],
                'phone'    => [],
                'notes'    => [],
                'kind'     => [
                    'default' => 'ecosystem'
                ],
                'rank' => ....
```

The problem is that all worked fine till now, and this error it's very strange becuase if i remove the file and his content, the page is still works, like it's in cache of something, the file now is uneditable, the var is not exists and i realy stuck here.

Thanks for help!

Comment: If this is on Laravel 5.3 or earlier see if you have a `compiled.php` class cache in your bootstrap cache folder

Comment: No it's `Laravel 5.4`, got only `packages.php` & `services.php` files in the bootsrap folder.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

`CompaniesController` already was exists in other namespace and the composer was built `dump-autoload` on the old path instead.

i removed the file from the old location and run `composer dump-autoload` and the problem solved.